# WPF MVVM-Light ComboBox and loading selected item

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls, mvvm-light

I have a modal window with some user information in it.  I am trying to get the ComboBoxes to automatically select a value based on the ID of the object that this Window is bound to.  I have tried everything I have seen on Stack and nothing works.  I can set SelectedIndex to a hard coded value but that doesn't work unless the IDs go in numeric order (1,2,3,4), which they do not.

Here is my ComboBox xaml:

```
  <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding Truck, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Trucks}" 
            SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.Driver.TruckId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" 
            SelectedValuePath="Id" 
            DisplayMemberPath="TruckNumber"/>
```

As you can see, I am pulling an ObservableCollection object in from another VM, so I have references to the windows DataContext that need to be found.  I can't figure out how to set the combo box so that the selected Truck is the Driver.TruckId that is being returned already.  The other information is showing up in text areas so I know the data is there, and I am not receiving a binding error.

EDIT:  What's even stranger is that I just used this one and it works AND my variable names are written in properly so this is REALLY confusing, the other above example is using an int as well.

```
 <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding DriverStatus, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
           ItemsSource="{Binding DriverStatuses}" 
           SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.Driver.StatusId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" 
           SelectedValuePath="Id" 
           DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Comment: Download snoopwpf.codeplex.com and investigate the bindings for those properties. If there is an error, you'll see it.

Comment: I don't see any errors

Comment: And it still does not work.

Comment: Do you assign a new instance of the collection to the Trucs property while the data-binding is active? This would break the binding. Furthermore, it is important to know that if `SelectedValue` is set before `ItemsSource`, the binding will break as well.

Comment: Show us your view model. It looks like you are setting `DataContext`, and then `ItemsSource`. So, as far as you dont have something like  `DriverStatus.DriverStatuses` in your view model, your binding is incorrect.